# Bootstrap 4 colors are not changing in Angular 9

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, angular9

I have made a custom scss file (`modified-bootstrap.scss`) to override bootstrap variables

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #84329b,
  "secondary": #02bceb
);
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"; // tried relative path too
```

Then imported it in a file named `base.scss` which is added in `angular.json`. Here is the `base.scss` file-

```
@import "./helpers";
@import "./custom";
@import "./modified-bootstrap";
```

And, here is my `angular.json` file's scss schematics, styles and scripts array-

```
      "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/assets/theme/base.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
        ...
        ...
        "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
       }
     }
```

Bootstrap is working fine but the colors are not getting overrode. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should the remove the "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" from the styles-array

```
      "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/assets/theme/base.scss"
        ],
```

because you already import the bootstrap sass'version in your base.scss.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue of what was causing the problem. This is the order in styles array of `angular.json`. My `base.scss` file was listed before the `bootstrap.min.css` which I think overriding my changes. Changing the order solved the problem. The list should be like this-

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    "src/assets/theme/base.scss",
],
```